# "Meine Mutter liebt es zu lesen" versus "Meine Mutter liebt lesen"

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

I looked up "My mother loves to read" on Google Translate, and it gave me more words than I expected.

> Meine Mutter liebt es zu lesen.

I would have expected the simpler **Meine Mutter liebt lesen**. What is the difference between the two sentences, if any? Why the addition of **es** and **zu**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Meine Mutter liebt **Lesen** (*Katzen*, *Bücher*, *Tanzen*, *Kochen*, ...)

Here, **Lesen** is the object. Notice that it is a noun and must be capitalized like any other noun such as *Katzen*, *Bücher*, *Tanzen*, *Kochen*, and so on.

> Meine Mutter liebt **es** *zu lesen* (*zu tanzen*, *zu kochen*).

Here, **es** is the object and *zu lesen* is the infinitive of the verb *lesen* + the word *zu*.

Comment: Is this construction particular to certain verbs like leben? Because you could alternatively say, Ich will schlafen (I want to sleep), where schlafen is the object of wanting and there is no **es** or **zu**.

Comment: I suppose that example is a bit different because wollen is a modal verb whereas leben is not. But perhaps this reveals my confusion about which kind of verbs need **es** and **zu** before an infinitive, and which do not.

Answer (score 3):

As always Google gives often grammatically correct but still awkward translations. You may occasionally hear the verbatim translation

> Meine Mutter liebt es zu lesen.

but this is a much too complicated sentence for everyday use. We'd simply say

> Meine Mutter liebt (das) Lesen.

or even shorter and more natural

> Meine Mutter liest gern(e).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a remark not on syntax but on style and expression:

To be on the safe side you should never translate English sentences with the word "love" into German sentences with "lieben" except when speaking of love as very strong emotional bond between humans. In proper German, you do not "love" (lieben) doing something, neither you "love" (lieben) products of any sort. You have to use other expressions since

> <strike>Meine Mutter liebt es zu lesen</strike>
>
> <strike>Mein Bruder liebt Computerspiele</strike>

will instantly be identified as a sentence formed by a non-native speaker. Cases where "love" can be used appropriately for things outside the realm of human relationship are scarce and difficult to locate.

Better (idomatic) ways to express what you want to say by "My mother loves reading" and so on are:

> Meine Mutter liest gern(e).
>
> Mein Bruder isst gern(e) Eis.
>
> Meine Mutter ist eine Vielleserin.
>
> Meine Mutter ist eine begeisterte Leserin.
>
> Mein Bruder mag Eis sehr gern(e).

or colloquially, sloppily, jocularly:

> Meine Schwester ist eine Leseratte.
>
> Mein Freund ist ein echter Bücherwurm.
>
> Mein kleiner Bruder ist verrückt nach Eis.
>
> Mein Onkel macht nichts lieber als Radfahren.
>
> Fritz hat einen Narren gefressen am Stricken.
>
> Mein Bruder ist ein Fußball-Narr.

However, speaking of love between humans:

> Ulrich liebt Helga.
>
> Die Mutter liebt ihre Kinder.
>
> Unsere Nachbarin liebt ihren Wellensittich.

The last one is not between humans, but would be an acceptable sentence anyway because supposedly the emotional bond is similar.

There may be one exception where "lieben" is appropriate in sentences describing the relationship of a person to a product e.g.

> Mein Bruder liebt Spaghetti mit Tomatensoße

I believe this is acceptable because it is slightly ironic. I communicate my opinion that my brother is so completely fixated on Spaghetti that his relationship to Spaghetti is nearly as intensive as the love he would (perhaps) feel for the pretty girl next door (if he wasn't that fixated on Spaghetti).

---

Note:

Recently, various providers of online services send around messages "Lieben Sie unsere App?", aiming at getting useful response to their product so to be able to improve it. Good idea, but on that specific question they always get my answer:

> Nein, ich liebe Ihre App nicht. Ich liebe meine Frau.

even when I like their app because it provides useful services and I would be inclined to give positive feedback. But obviously they do not take the effort to translate their questionnaires properly e.g. by asking a native speaker. Or their native staff is utterly incompetent - possibly brainwashed by too much internet Denglish, and probably a bunch of miserable translations in the soundtrack of Hollywood movies.

Likewise, the slogan of one of the larger fastfood suppliers "Ich liebe es" - obviously derived directly from English "I love it" - is gross nonsense in German.

Comment: Die gesamte Antwort beruht ja auf der Ansicht, dass _lieben_ nur zwischen Lebewesen, nicht jedoch zwischen einem Lebewesen und einer Sache gebraucht werden sollte. Dem widerspreche ich vehement, und zwar nicht nur in dem als eine Ausnahme deklarierten Fall der Ironie, sondern ganz grundsätzlich. Und das Wörterbuch stimmt mir da zu; siehe b) und c) beim Eintrag _lieben_ im DWDS (https://www.dwds.de/wb/lieben).

Comment: Die Sprachpraxis in dem Teil der deutschsprachigen Welt, in dem ich lebe, ist halt so. Ich sehe das auch weniger normativ denn deskriptiv. - Kein vernünftiger Mensch würde in einer Alltagssituation sagen "Paul liebt es zu lesen". Allenfalls in einem Roman aus dem späten 19. Jahrhundert würde man so einen Satz vielleicht noch finden. Oder man strebt einen hochgestochenen Sprachstil an - aber wo sollte man das tun?

Comment: Spaghetti zu lieben ist nicht, auch nicht ein wenig, ironisch. Ironie ist es, wenn die Tante sagt "Magst Du Spaghetti, Toni?", Toni den Mund verzieht und die Mutter kommentiert "Toni liebt Spaghetti". Lieben drückt eine stärkere emotionale Bindung aus, als mögen und wird so verwendet. Ob Du es so verwendest ist nicht der Punkt, sondern wie es im Deutschen verwendet wird. Ich liebe auch kein McDonald-Essen, aber das ist ein inhaltlicher Dissens, kein sprachlicher. Hochgestochen ist es auch nicht im geringsten.

Comment: Sprichst du so im Alltag? Das kann ja sein. Gleichwohl ist es ein heikler Punkt insbesondere für neue Sprecher des Deutschen, die mit einem englischen Sprachhintergrund daherkommen. Für diese ist es ein guter Rat, "lieben" möglichst sparsam zu gebrauchen, weil sie sich, wenn sie es so inflationär einsetzen, wie es im Englischen üblich ist, damit verrennen.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann, Zitat: "Kein vernünftiger Mensch würde in einer Alltagssituation sagen 'Paul liebt es zu lesen'". Na wie witzig, dass ich erst vor zwei Wochen den Satz "Ich liebe das Lesen" in einer Selbstbeschreibung über mich geschrieben habe. Und es gibt viele andere Dinge, die ich liebe und das auch völlig normal finde so zu sagen. Aber vielleicht bin ich eben kein vernünftiger Mensch ...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, nochmal: Mit _lieben_ liegt man nicht falsch oder verrennt sich, was, wie ich schon mal weiter oben geschrieben habe, durch die Bedeutungen b) und c) im DWDS bestätigt wird.